# How to change an array of JavaScript items using wp_localize_script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a javascript file that make a call to the suppressed.js script. I want to be able to use wp_localizee_script in order to change the paths to the images and caption text from wordpress. Here is the javascript file:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  var CHAKRA = window.CHAKRA || {};

  /* ==================================================
     Mobile Navigation
  ================================================== */
  /* Clone Menu for use later */
  var mobileMenuClone = $('#menu').clone().attr('id', 'navigation-mobile');

  CHAKRA.mobileNav = function() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    // Show Menu or Hide the Menu
    if (windowWidth <= 979) {
      if ($('#mobile-nav').length > 0) {
        mobileMenuClone.insertAfter('#menu');
        $('#navigation-mobile #menu-nav').attr('id', 'menu-nav-mobile');
      }
    } else {
      $('#navigation-mobile').css('display', 'none');
      if ($('#mobile-nav').hasClass('open')) {
        $('#mobile-nav').removeClass('open');
      }
    }
  }

  // Call the Event for Menu 
  CHAKRA.listenerMenu = function() {
    $('#mobile-nav').on('click', function(e) {
      $(this).toggleClass('open');

      $('#navigation-mobile').stop().slideToggle(350, 'easeOutExpo');

      e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#menu-nav-mobile a').on('click', function() {
      $('#mobile-nav').removeClass('open');
      $('#navigation-mobile').slideUp(350, 'easeOutExpo');
    });
  }


  /* ==================================================
     Slider Options
  ================================================== */

  CHAKRA.slider = function() {
    $.supersized({
      // Functionality
      slideshow: 1, // Slideshow on/off
      autoplay: 1, // Slideshow starts playing automatically
      start_slide: 1, // Start slide (0 is random)
      stop_loop: 0, // Pauses slideshow on last slide
      random: 0, // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
      slide_interval: 12000, // Length between transitions
      transition: 2, // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
      transition_speed: 300, // Speed of transition
      new_window: 1, // Image links open in new window/tab
      pause_hover: 0, // Pause slideshow on hover
      keyboard_nav: 1, // Keyboard navigation on/off
      performance: 1, // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
      image_protect: 1, // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

      // Size & Position         
      min_width: 0, // Min width allowed (in pixels)
      min_height: 0, // Min height allowed (in pixels)
      vertical_center: 1, // Vertically center background
      horizontal_center: 1, // Horizontally center background
      fit_always: 0, // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
      fit_portrait: 1, // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
      fit_landscape: 0, // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

      // Components       
      slide_links: 'blank', // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
      thumb_links: 0, // Individual thumb links for each slide
      thumbnail_navigation: 0, // Thumbnail navigation
      slides: [ // Slideshow Images
        {
          image: 'http://fatcatmediahouse.com/theoneandonly2014theme/wp-content/themes/fatcat/_include/img/slider-images/image01.jpg',
          title: '<div class="slide-content">Chakra</div>',
          thumb: '',
          url: ''
        }, {
          image: 'http://fatcatmediahouse.com/theoneandonly2014theme/wp-content/themes/fatcat/_include/img/slider-images/image02.jpg',
          title: '<div class="slide-content">Responsive Design</div>',
          thumb: '',
          url: ''
        }, {
          image: 'http://fatcatmediahouse.com/theoneandonly2014theme/wp-content/themes/fatcat/_include/img/slider-images/image03.jpg',
          title: '<div class="slide-content">FullScreen Gallery</div>',
          thumb: '',
          url: ''
        }, {
          image: 'http://fatcatmediahouse.com/theoneandonly2014theme/wp-content/themes/fatcat/_include/img/slider-images/image04.jpg',
          title: '<div class="slide-content">Showcase Your Work</div>',
          thumb: '',
          url: ''
        }
      ],

      // Theme Options      
      progress_bar: 0, // Timer for each slide       
      mouse_scrub: 0

    });

  }


  /* ==================================================
     Navigation Fix
  ================================================== */

  CHAKRA.nav = function() {
    $('.sticky-nav').waypoint('sticky');
  }


  /* ==================================================
     Filter Works
  ================================================== */

  CHAKRA.filter = function() {
    if ($('#projects').length > 0) {
      var $container = $('#projects');

      $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
        $container.isotope({
          // options
          animationEngine: 'best-available',
          itemSelector: '.item-thumbs',
          layoutMode: 'fitRows'
        });
      });


      // filter items when filter link is clicked
      var $optionSets = $('#options .option-set'),
        $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

      $optionLinks.click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        // don't proceed if already selected
        if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
          return false;
        }
        var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
        $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');

        // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
        var options = {},
          key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
          value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
        // parse 'false' as false boolean
        value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
        options[key] = value;
        if (key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function') {
          // changes in layout modes need extra logic
          changeLayoutMode($this, options)
        } else {
          // otherwise, apply new options
          $container.isotope(options);
        }

        return false;
      });
    }
  }


  /* ==================================================
     FancyBox
  ================================================== */

  CHAKRA.fancyBox = function() {
    if ($('.fancybox').length > 0 || $('.fancybox-media').length > 0 || $('.fancybox-various').length > 0) {

      $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        padding: 0,
        beforeShow: function() {
          this.title = $(this.element).attr('title');
          this.title = '<h4>' + this.title + '</h4>' + '<p>' + $(this.element).parent().find('img').attr('alt') + '</p>';
        },
        helpers: {
          title: {
            type: 'inside'
          },
        }
      });

      $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
        helpers: {
          media: {}
        }
      });

      $(".fancybox-various").fancybox({
        maxWidth: 800,
        maxHeight: 600,
        fitToView: false,
        width: '70%',
        height: '70%',
        autoSize: false,
        closeClick: false,
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none'
      });
    }
  }


  /* ==================================================
     Contact Form
  ================================================== */

  CHAKRA.contactForm = function() {
    $("#contact-submit").on('click', function() {
      $contact_form = $('#contact-form');

      var fields = $contact_form.serialize();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "_include/php/contact.php",
        data: fields,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {

          if (response.status) {
            $('#contact-form input').val('');
            $('#contact-form textarea').val('');
          }

          $('#response').empty().html(response.html);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  }


  /* ==================================================
     Twitter Feed
  ================================================== */

  CHAKRA.tweetFeed = function() {
    var valueTop = -64; // Margin Top Value

    $("#ticker").tweet({
      username: "Bluxart", // Change this with YOUR ID
      page: 1,
      avatar_size: 0,
      count: 10,
      template: "{text}{time}",
      filter: function(t) {
        return !/^@\w+/.test(t.tweet_raw_text);
      },
      loading_text: "loading ..."
    }).bind("loaded", function() {
      var ul = $(this).find(".tweet_list");
      var ticker = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          ul.find('li:first').animate({
            marginTop: valueTop + 'px'
          }, 500, 'linear', function() {
            $(this).detach().appendTo(ul).removeAttr('style');
          });
          ticker();
        }, 5000);
      };
      ticker();
    });

  }


  /* ==================================================
     Menu Highlight
  ================================================== */

  CHAKRA.menu = function() {
    $('#menu-nav, #menu-nav-mobile').onePageNav({
      currentClass: 'current',
      changeHash: false,
      scrollSpeed: 750,
      scrollOffset: 30,
      scrollThreshold: 0.5,
      easing: 'easeOutExpo',
      filter: ':not(.external)'
    });
  }

  /* ==================================================
     Next Section
  ================================================== */

  CHAKRA.goSection = function() {
    $('#nextsection').on('click', function() {
      $target = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 30;

      $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: $target
      }, 750, 'easeOutExpo');
      return false;
    });
  }

  /* ==================================================
     GoUp
  ================================================== */

  CHAKRA.goUp = function() {
    $('#goUp').on('click', function() {
      $target = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 30;

      $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: $target
      }, 750, 'easeOutExpo');
      return false;
    });
  }


  /* ==================================================
   Scroll to Top
  ================================================== */

  CHAKRA.scrollToTop = function() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
      didScroll = false;

    var $arrow = $('#back-to-top');

    $arrow.click(function(e) {
      $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: "0"
      }, 750, 'easeOutExpo');
      e.preventDefault();
    })

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      didScroll = true;
    });

    setInterval(function() {
      if (didScroll) {
        didScroll = false;

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 1000) {
          $arrow.css('display', 'block');
        } else {
          $arrow.css('display', 'none');
        }
      }
    }, 250);
  }

  /* ==================================================
     Thumbs / Social Effects
  ================================================== */

  // Fix Hover on Touch Devices
  CHAKRA.utils = function() {

    $('.item-thumbs').bind('touchstart', function() {
      $(".active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });

  }

  /* ==================================================
     Accordion
  ================================================== */

  CHAKRA.accordion = function() {
    var accordion_trigger = $('.accordion-heading.accordionize');

    accordion_trigger.delegate('.accordion-toggle', 'click', function(event) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('inactive');
      } else {
        accordion_trigger.find('.active').addClass('inactive');
        accordion_trigger.find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).removeClass('inactive');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  }

  /* ==================================================
     Toggle
  ================================================== */

  CHAKRA.toggle = function() {
    var accordion_trigger_toggle = $('.accordion-heading.togglize');

    accordion_trigger_toggle.delegate('.accordion-toggle', 'click', function(event) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('inactive');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('inactive');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      }
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  }

  /* ==================================================
     Tooltip
  ================================================== */

  CHAKRA.toolTip = function() {
    $('a[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
  }

  /* ==================================================
     Map
  ================================================== */

  CHAKRA.map = function() {
    if ($('.map').length > 0) {

      $('.map').each(function(i, e) {

        $map = $(e);
        $map_id = $map.attr('id');
        $map_lat = $map.attr('data-mapLat');
        $map_lon = $map.attr('data-mapLon');
        $map_zoom = parseInt($map.attr('data-mapZoom'));
        $map_title = $map.attr('data-mapTitle');



        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng($map_lat, $map_lon);
        var options = {
          scrollwheel: false,
          draggable: false,
          zoomControl: false,
          disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
          disableDefaultUI: true,
          zoom: $map_zoom,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var styles = [{
          stylers: [{
            hue: "#2F3238"
          }, {
            saturation: -20
          }]
        }, {
          featureType: "road",
          elementType: "geometry",
          stylers: [{
            lightness: 100
          }, {
            visibility: "simplified"
          }]
        }, {
          featureType: "road",
          elementType: "labels",
          stylers: [{
            visibility: "off"
          }]
        }];

        var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {
          name: "Styled Map"
        });

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById($map_id), options);

        var image = '_include/img/marker.png';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map,
          title: $map_title,
          icon: image
        });

        map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
        map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

        var contentString = '<p><strong>Company Name</strong><br>Address here</p>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

      });
    }
  }

  /* ==================================================
   Init
  ================================================== */

  CHAKRA.slider();

  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Call placeholder.js to enable Placeholder Property for IE9
    Modernizr.load([{
      test: Modernizr.input.placeholder,
      nope: '_include/js/placeholder.js',
      complete: function() {
        if (!Modernizr.input.placeholder) {
          Placeholders.init({
            live: true,
            hideOnFocus: false,
            className: "yourClass",
            textColor: "#999"
          });
        }
      }
    }]);

    // Preload the page with jPreLoader
    $('body').jpreLoader({
      splashID: "#jSplash",
      showSplash: true,
      showPercentage: true,
      autoClose: true
    });

    CHAKRA.nav();
    CHAKRA.mobileNav();
    CHAKRA.listenerMenu();
    CHAKRA.menu();
    CHAKRA.goSection();
    CHAKRA.goUp();
    CHAKRA.filter();
    CHAKRA.fancyBox();
    CHAKRA.contactForm();
    CHAKRA.tweetFeed();
    CHAKRA.scrollToTop();
    CHAKRA.utils();
    CHAKRA.accordion();
    CHAKRA.toggle();
    CHAKRA.toolTip();
    CHAKRA.map();
  });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    CHAKRA.mobileNav();
  });

});
```

Now here is my php

```
// Hook into the 'wp_enqueue_scripts' action
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'main_scripts' );
function main_scripts(){
     // Default JS (Use wp_localize_script to pass in php)
     wp_deregister_script( 'main' );
     wp_register_script( 'main', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'_include/js/main.js', false, '1.0',    true );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'main' );
}
```

How do I change the part of the script where the image is if I have the following advance custom fields

```
<?php the_field('image1') ?>
<?php the_field('image2') ?>
<?php the_field('image3') ?>
<?php the_field('image4') ?>
<?php the_field('caption1') ?>
<?php the_field('caption2') ?>
<?php the_field('caption3') ?>
<?php the_field('caption4') ?>
```

The Javascript that I am trying to change is:

```
slides: [ // Slideshow Images
        {
          image: 'http://fatcatmediahouse.com/theoneandonly2014theme/wp-content/themes/fatcat/_include/img/slider-images/image01.jpg',
          title: '<div class="slide-content">Chakra</div>',
          thumb: '',
          url: ''
        }, {
          image: 'http://fatcatmediahouse.com/theoneandonly2014theme/wp-content/themes/fatcat/_include/img/slider-images/image02.jpg',
          title: '<div class="slide-content">Responsive Design</div>',
          thumb: '',
          url: ''
        }, {
          image: 'http://fatcatmediahouse.com/theoneandonly2014theme/wp-content/themes/fatcat/_include/img/slider-images/image03.jpg',
          title: '<div class="slide-content">FullScreen Gallery</div>',
          thumb: '',
          url: ''
        }, {
          image: 'http://fatcatmediahouse.com/theoneandonly2014theme/wp-content/themes/fatcat/_include/img/slider-images/image04.jpg',
          title: '<div class="slide-content">Showcase Your Work</div>',
          thumb: '',
          url: ''
        }
      ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_localize_script` will not actually change the values already in a script. Rather, it enables you to set global Javascript variables, which can then be utilized by a script. See below.

PHP

```
$images = array(
    array("image" => 'slider-images/image01.jpg', "title" => "Chakra"),
    array("image" => 'slider-images/image02.jpg', "title" => "Another title")
);

wp_register_script( 'main', trailingslashit( THEME_URI ) .'_include/js/main.js', false, '1.0',    true );
wp_localize_script( 'main', 'My_Slide_Images', $images );
wp_enqueue_script( 'main' );
```

In the JS file

```
slides: window.My_Slide_Images
```

Comment: Thanks I am going to try this.